# Microsoft Teams Custom Tab Application - geolocation issue

Tags: javascript, geolocation, microsoft-teams, google-geolocation

I created a custom teams application using Microsoft Teams Toolkit for VS Code. I am trying to read the location from the app. I am able to load the coordinates in the Browser and Android version of teams but it fails in the Desktop version of teams with the below error.

```
Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received.
```

The function to load the Location-

```
 const getLocation = () => {
      let that = this;
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          alert('got position');
          var positionInfo = "Your current position is (Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
           alert(positionInfo);
        }, (error) => {
          alert("Error: " + error.message);
        }, { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 75000 });
      } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }
```

It might be a problem with the `navigator.geolocation().getCurrentPosition` API. Any leads on this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I will let this question be here for anyone looking for an answer or if anyone finds an update to this.

I found this official documentation from MSFT that states geolocation API is not fully supported in the teams desktop client currently and they suggest using the getLocation API of TeamsSDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=desktop

[image]